# Javascript Hex color changer using .toString()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a basic hex color changer using javascript but I'm encountering issues with when converting the randomly outputted decimal into hex. Below is my code. I have a console output for both the variables both before and after using .toString conversion but they both remain the same.

```js
let colors = "#";
//get button
let button = document.getElementById("button");
//add event listener
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  //randomizer
  var randomColor = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215)];
  let hexColor = colors + randomColor.toString(16);

  //get container
  let container = document.getElementById("container");

  container.style.background = hexColor;
  console.log(hexColor);
  console.log(randomColor);
})
```

```html
<button id="button">Click Me</button>

<div id="container">container</div>
```

Comment: ```use randomColor();```

Comment: Where is the `randomColor` coming from?

Comment: @manas missed it in the code, added now:                                                                
 var randomColor = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215)];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `randomColor` for some reason is array `[1234]`, make it simple number.

When using `[1234].toString(16)` you get all array values concatenated using [`Array.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) (that does not accept any arguments)

```js
let colors = "#";
//get button
let button = document.getElementById("button");
//add event listener
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  //randomizer
  var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215);
  let hexColor = colors + randomColor.toString(16);

  //get container
  let container = document.getElementById("container");

  container.style.background = hexColor;
  console.log('Hex: ' + hexColor, 'Dec: ' + randomColor);
})
```

```html
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
<div id="container">C O N T A I N E R</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a random color by using `getRandomColor` function like this:

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

    //get button
    let button = document.getElementById("button");
    //add event listener
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      
      //get container
      let container = document.getElementById("button");

      container.style.background = getRandomColor();
    })
```

```html
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```